# It was vs it is

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Good evening ,i was wondering if you can tell me what is the correct form of this setence.Since I am talking about a book ,it is a little confusing :)

The social worker visited Fanella's house due to see if **it was** a safe place for children. Furthermore, to have a talk with her

Thank you so much

Comment: He visited at the time, to see if it was at the time. We don't know if it's safe now. Indeed everyone involved may long be gone. Maybe even the house.

Comment: The sentence is correct as it is. The social worker's visit was in the past, so the verb is in the past tense.